pandas complex merge
How can I merge these two dataframes?
df1
enter image description here
df2

Rule:

Merge based on callsign and re (if not null). If de and d_runway do not match, add a label indicating a mismatch.
Merge based on re if callsign is null.
If both callsign and re are null, merge based on de and d_runway.

There is also a timestamp that plays a key role in merging such that each dataframe has a timestamp and can only be matched if the difference is within 900 seconds
Output


What are those n values?  Do those indicate a ditto mark?  So those records do not have a key?  It looks to me like you will need to merge these by hand, row by row, based on your rules.

sorry, typo there. it is supposed to be an empty field

You have so far not yet made this reproducible. Show us the python code that you tried, and its results. Also, when implementing a complex multi-part business rule, it makes sense to tackle just "callsign", or "callsign with timestamp", score a win, then start worrying about "re" and other details.

Your expected output is surprising. Why 2 different columns for callsign and re if you merged on them? both XYZ456 are not on the same row.

Please dont use image for sample input and output, use data in tabular markdown format
